# Count strings within an element of a list

Tags: python, python-3.8

Let's say I have a list, l, which has sentences as elements. For example l = [boy boy, girl, hand foot foot ...]. I want to be able to loop through the list and find out which elements of my list has duplicates. I tried the counter function but didn't get the desired result:

```
from _collections import Counter

print(Counter(l))
```

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: What is the expected output for `l = ['boy boy', 'girl', 'hand foot foot']`?

Comment: Please update your question with some more example data and expected results. I'm not sure I understand what you are after from your explanation.

Comment: That is not valid Python code. Please provide a *valid* assignment to `l`.

Comment: That is not what the original question was. The list should be `'boy boy', 'girl'`...

Comment: @buran Please do not guess at the OP's intent.

Comment: @chepner - it's clear what the assignment is. The desired output is unclear. Just wanted to improve the question. Whatever...

Comment: @buran It's much more likely that yatu's interpretation is closer to the OP's intent than your edit was.

Comment: @chepner, yes, I saw missing quotes and corrected them, just before you revert all my edits - check edit history. There were multiple issues and I submit an edit and then saw missing quotes.

Comment: Let the OP correct their own code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the length of the **[set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)** of the words in the sentence i.e., the unique words is not the same as the length of the **[list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)** of all the words in the sentence:

```
sentences = ['boy boy', 'girl', 'hand foot foot']
sentences_with_duplicates = [s 
                            for s in sentences 
                            if len(set(s.split())) != len(s.split())]
print(sentences_with_duplicates)
```

**Output:**

```
['boy boy', 'hand foot foot']
```

Comment: Yes, that is my desired output. Can you walk me through what function you used when you did sentences_with_duplicates = [s 
                            for s in sentences 
                            if len(set(s.split())) != len(s.split())]

Comment: See here: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python as well as click on the links in the answer. Additionally here is the documentation for the split function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: @SohamPhadke Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html

The `Counter` class of `collections` module offers a utility to find the number of appearance of a string in a list of strings as dictionary.

In the following function you will get a list of strings which have been duplicated.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_duplicate_str(list_of_str):
    """
    This function returns a list of duplicate strings appeared in given list of strings.
    @param list_of_str: List of strings
    @return : List of strings
    """
    str_counter_dict = Counter(list_of_str)
    list_of_duplicate_str = [key for key in str_counter_dict.keys() if str_counter_dict[key] > 1]
    return list_of_duplicate_str

# Testing the function
print(get_duplicate_str(["boy", "boy", "girl", "hand", "foot", "foot"]))

# Output
['boy', 'foot']
```

Answer (score -1):

you can convert this list into dictionary and again convert into list so all duplicate are removed

```
mylist = ['boy' 'boy', 'girl', ,'hand' ,'foot' ]
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
print(mylist)
```

[image]